# How can I easily convert legacy code to WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi I have the following legacy code. I would like to create a WCF without going to create all the contracts and other junk MS has built into their code. There are more then 100 commands I would have to create for every method and command. It would be simpler just to use the existing code.

```
 using System;
 using System.Net.Sockets;

 namespace Server
 {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(55555);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Server Started");
        ServerLobby.Initialize();
        ServerLobby.reader.Load("Users.xml");

        while (true)
        {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            Client client = new Client(clientSocket);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you upgrading if you don't want to upgrade?

Comment: metro app will not connect to it

Comment: You can't call it Metro anymore... Oh boy now you got me saying it.

Comment: newbie... give me a break , please I have spent the last week trying to do this, I went from tcp sockets to asmx, only to realize asmx is disconnected and holds no session state

Comment: wait a second, I tried using the sample code from MS sdk but the sockets using Windows.Networking.Sockets was not able to connent from the metro app, the other code I wrote only worked when i shut down the application, then the connection decided to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to define a simple WCF interface that will call your legacy methods. You still gotta fill in all that *"junk"* though.

```
public interface ICommandServer
{
    void Execute(string command, string[] args);
}
```

Comment: Sorry i am kinda new how would i do this with the above code ?

Comment: @user1625293 - Are you asking me to give you a step by step tutorial on implementing a basic WCF service?

Comment: @user1625293 - Just come back with a specific question if you have too much trouble.

Comment: would it not be simpler to make a wcf contract that passes a string to the existing code ?

Comment: @user1625293 - You could have one contract with 100 methods if that's how you've broken up your code. I always try and keep the contract as simple as possible though.